# Correct variadic pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20, stdtuple

I am working on C++20 implementation of `tuple`:

```
template<size_t INDEX, typename T>
struct wrap { [[no_unique_address]] T data {}; };

template<typename...>
class base {};

template<size_t... INDEX, typename... Ts>
class base<index_sequence<INDEX...>, Ts...> : public wrap<INDEX, Ts>... {
public:
    constexpr base( const Ts &... args ) : /* !! HERE SHALL THE MAGIC COME */ {}
};

template<typename... Ts>
class tuple : public base<index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...> {
public:
    /* Inherit base constructors */
    using base<index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...>::base;
};
```

**My question is:** How to correctly implement the code in place of `/* !! HERE SHALL THE MAGIC COME */` to call base, means `wrap<>` constructor - the `wrap` copy constructor taking the corresponding instance of `T` (expanded from `base`'s template variadic pack `Ts`) hold in `args`?

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter pack expansion also applies to member initializer lists, so you can simply do this:

```
template<size_t INDEX, typename T>
struct wrap { [[no_unique_address]] T data {}; };

template<typename...>
class base {};

template<size_t... INDEX, typename... Ts>
class base<std::index_sequence<INDEX...>, Ts...> : public wrap<INDEX, Ts>... {
 public:
  constexpr base(const Ts&... args) : wrap<INDEX, Ts>{args}... {}
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/cxbs319Mx)